# Is it possible to tell if a .net application was developed with unlicensed Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build, licensing, build-process

We contracted a guy to build .net app. His team is in India, and am afraid they may not have licensed softwares their, which may eventually get us in troubles.

Is their anyway I can tell if the end product he deliver was developed with licensed Visual Studio ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there actually is - especially because Visual Studio itself doesn't compile the code, if it's C# then its the CSC.exe (VBC.exe for Visual Basic) file that does the work and that itself comes with the .Net framework and is free.